# Can :hover apply to generic element tags specific to a parent div?

Tags: php, html, css

I am using a bunch of divs (created with PHP) to generate a block of clickable elements. What I need to do is apply some styles to these generic elements, rather than to specific ones, yet using the code below seems to be invalid.

```
#Container {
height: 80%;
width: 60%;
background-color: green;
}
#Container div:hover {
background-color: blue;
}

<div id="Container">
  <div style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;">    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XD2eZ/

So I am not sure if it is an issue that a generic div element cannot be styled as a sub-element AND have a :hover attribute that operates properly. I know that classes or id's can be specified to handle this, but have thousands of unique divs. I also cannot use

```
#Container:hover div{ background-color: blue;}
```

As it ALSO seems to be invalid, but I need to select the one element from a block, and not all at once.

Any ideas here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: inline styles take precedence over your current hover selector

Comment: In addition to @PatrickEvans's comment, throw in `!important` and that should work. ie. `background-color: blue !important;`

Comment: According to @PatrickEvans' comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/XD2eZ/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you remove the background color from the HTML, and apply it using css:

```css
#Container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: green;
}
#Container div {background-color: red;}

#Container div:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XD2eZ/1/

The reasone is [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) - a `style` attribute rule is much more specific (stronger) than an ID + element rule.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, should have remembered that.